# Data from byte array

Tags: c#, file, stream, binary, kinect

I'm trying to read the bytes in the stream at each frame.
I want to be able to read the position and the timestamp information that is stored on a file I have created.

The stream is a stream of recorded skeleton data and it is in encoded binary format

```
Stream recordStream;
byte[] results;
using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(@".....\Stream01.recorded", FileMode.Open))
{
    if (SourceStream.CanRead)
    {
        results = new byte[recordStream.Length];
        SourceStream.Read(results, 0, (int)recordStream.Length);
    }
}
```

The file should be read and the Read method should read the current sequence of bytes before advances the position in the stream.

Is there a way to pull out the data (position and timestamp) I want from the bytes read, and save it in separate variables before it advances?

Could using the binary reader give me the capabilities to do this.

```
BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(recordStream);
```

I have save the file as .recorded. I have also saved it as .txt to see what is contained in the file, but since it is encoded, it is not understandable.

Update:
I tried running the code with breakpoints to see if it enters the function with my binaryreader and it crashes with an error: ArgumentException was unhandled. Stream was not readable, on the BinaryReader initialization and declaration

```
BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(recordStream);
```

The file type was .recorded.

Comment: That completely depends on the format of the binary file. Do you have a file format definition available? The fact that it's binary means you need to seek to the specified destination and read from there..

Comment: The file format is stream of skeleton data that includes timestamp (long type), frame number (int type), floor clip plane (float type), array of skeleton data that includes tracking state that is set, tracking id (int type), skeleton position (float type), joint information, bone orientation, etc.... .. How would I seek a specified destination to read from there?

Comment: Your updated question, even though related, should be separated from this one to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide any information about the format of the data you are trying to read.
However, using the BinaryReader is exactly what you need to do.

It exposes methods to read data from the stream and convert them to various types.

Consider the following example:

```
var filename = "pathtoyourfile";

using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    var x = reader.ReadByte();
    var y = reader.ReadInt16();
    var z = reader.ReadBytes(10);
}
```

It really depends on the format of your data though.

**Update**
Even though I feel I've already provided all the information you need,
let's use your data.

You say each record in your data starts with

[long: timestamp][int: framenumber]

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    var timestamp = reader.ReadInt64();
    var frameNumber = reader.ReadInt32();

    //At this point you have the timestamp and the frame number
    //you can now do whatever you want with it and decide whether or not
    //to continue, after that you just continue reading
}
```

How you continue reading depends on the format of the remaining part of the records
If all fields in a record have a specific length, then you either (depending on the
choice you made knowing the values of the timestamp and the frame number) continue
reading all the fields for that record OR you simply advance to a position in the stream
that contains the next record. For example if each record is 100 bytes long, if you want to skip this record after you got the first two fields:

```
stream.Seek(88, SeekOrigin.Current); 
//88 here because the first two fields take 12 bytes -> (100 - 8 + 4)
```

If the records have a variable length the solution is similar, but you'll have to
take into account the length of the various fields (which should be defined by
length fields preceding the variable length fields)

As for knowing if the first 8 bytes really do represent a timestamp,
there's no real way of knowing for sure... remember in the end the stream just contains
a series of individual bytes that have no meaning whatsoever except for the meaning
given to them by your file format. Either you have to revise the file format or you could
try checking if the value of 'timestamp' in the example above even makes sense.

Is this a file format you have defined yourself, if so... perhaps you are making it to complicated and might want to look at solutions such as Google Protocol Buffers or Apache Thrift.

If this is still not what you are looking for, you will have to redefine your question.

Comment: the data is recorded in an encoded binary format, and contains timestamp (long type), frame number (int type), floor clip plane (float type), array of skeleton data that includes tracking state that is set, tracking id (int type), skeleton position (float type), joint information, bone orientation, etc.... , as mentioned in my above comment.... If there is so much information included how can I know to read just both the position and the timestamp (if possible) before advancing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

You need to know the exact definition of the entire file. You create a struct based on this file format:

```
struct YourFileFormat {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long Timestamp;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int FrameNumber;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    //.. etc..
}
```

Then, using a `BinaryReader`, you can either read each field individually for each frame:

```
// assume br is an instantiated BinaryReader..
YourFileFormat file = new YourFileFormat();

file.Timestamp = br.ReadInt64();
file.FrameNumber = br.ReadInt32();
// etc..
```

Or, you can read the entire file in and have the Marshalling classes copy everything into the struct for you..

```
byte[] fileContent = br.ReadBytes(sizeof(YourFileFormat));

GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(fileContent, GCHandleType.Pinned); // or pinning it via the "fixed" keyword in an unsafe context
file = (YourFileFormat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(YourFileFormat));
gcHandle.Free();
```

However, this assumes you'll know the exact size of the file. With this method though.. each frame (assuming you know how many there are) can be a fixed size array within this struct for that to work.

Bottom line: Unless you know the size of what you want to skip.. you can't hope to get the data from the file you require.

Comment: I agree, but is it possible to know if the first 4 bytes you read are the timestamp (long type) or something else prior to advancing. Is there a way to check what type it is (that is encoded in binary there) and using the right binary reader method to call out. All the read method types advances once it is called out, but I want to only advance if it actually gets the info I want and to skip on those I dont want.

Comment: No. If you read a `long` but the data is meant to be read as two `int`'s.. then you've already failed. This is why file formats have definitions.. so you know what to expect and in what order to read it in.